# Validation with html form only gives if statement

Tags: javascript

No matter how many characters I enter, it only gives the if statement and not the else.
is there a typo I entered somewhere I am not seeing, or does the function not work if there are two inputs?

```js
function valid_Function(){
    var x, text;

    x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
        text = "Input not valid";
    }
    else {
        text = "Input OK";
    }
    document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
form input {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
form [type="submit"] {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    background: skyblue;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
form [type="submit"]:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(92, 228, 252, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
        <input for="fname" id="name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
        <input for="lname" id="name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
        <input onclick="valid_Function()" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="valid"></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("name").value.trim().length`, You are looking for the `length` of the value-string and not the actual `value` of the input.

Comment: IDs should be unique in your HTML, so change one to `id="first_name"` and the other to `id="last_name"`

Comment: Why would a first name or a last name *be a number* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The couple issues noted in the comments are causing your code to break.

1. [IDs in HTML need to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), so having 2 elements with `id="name"` will cause problems in JavaScript
2. Assuming you meant to check the length of first/last names rather than comparing the *values* to the integers `1` and `10`, the code should be checking [the `.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) in your conditionals.

Assuming you want to run this check separately for each name input, here is the adjusted code to validate first and last name separately. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event for more information about handling form submission events.

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the form from submitting right away so the rest of the validation can run

  var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name").value.trim();
  var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name").value.trim();
  var text;

  if (firstName.length < 1 || firstName.length > 10) {
    text = "First name is not valid";
  } else if (lastName.length < 1 || lastName.length > 10) {
    text = "Last name is not valid";
  } else {
    text = "Input OK";
  }
  document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = text;

  return false; // this stops the form from continuing to submit, you may or may not want this line here
});
```

```css
form input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

form [type="submit"] {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: skyblue;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

form [type="submit"]:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(92, 228, 252, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input for="fname" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
  <input for="lname" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="valid"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still new to JavaScript (Only first week) I just wanted to make sure I understand exactly what the code is telling me.
With .value.trim(), it's telling the browser to target the firstName value and then trim it using the if statement below.
I just have a hard time understanding when you would use the .value or the .innerHTML after you call the document.get.

Comment: `value` should be used to get or set the value attribute of an element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), `innerHTML` should be used if you want to get or set the HTML markup of an element (see Examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). I'm using `trim` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to quickly remove spaces at the beginning or end of an input. The main use is if somebody enters only spaces, validation will fail because it will be seen as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

> No matter how many characters I enter, it only gives the if statement and not the else

Yes because isNaN will always return true if you give it a non number string and that's what is happening with you, if you try and input a number between 1 and 9 then your else will be executed.

Your validation works with number type inputs but since you want to validate a text input(name) then it can be done like this

your if statement

```
if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid";
}
```

should be

```
if(x === "" || x.length > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid";
}
```

because you need to check if the input is empty and if it is larger than 10 chars, besides I noticed you have two inputs with the same id!, the id is something unique it's not like classes, so pls change your HTML code

Comment: Well first he's using a text type input, and the place holder is saying First Name so it's indeed expecting a string and not a number, but from his JS code it seems he's doing a validation for an input type number and wants it to be bigger than one and less than 10 so [1-9] digit, but I assumed he just took that validation code from somewhere on the net, and he doesn't know what he's really doing, so I changed his validation code to works as he may expect

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple truthy check?

```
if (!x) {
        text = "Input not valid";
    }
    else {
        text = "Input OK";
    }
```

And, if you just want to make sure the length remains less than 10, then

```
 if (!x || x.length> 10) {
        text = "Input not valid";
    }
    else {
        text = "Input OK";
    }
```